# Storing Listview items into list and retrieving subitems

Tags: c#

I'm trying to store my listview into a list which has two columns and print it out to text. I'm able to do so - to some extent... but I can't seem to get the subitem in the second column to show. So far this is what I have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < netchart.Items.Count; i++)
{
    netchart.Items[i].Selected = true;
}

List<string> val = netchart.SelectedItems
                               .Cast<ListViewItem>()
                               .Select(listViewItem => listViewItem.Text)
                               .ToList();

if (val != null)
{
    foreach (var wid in val)
        output.Text = output.Text + "\n" + wid.ToString() ;
}

for (int i = 0; i < netchart.Items.Count; i++)
{
    netchart.Items[i].Selected = false;
}
```

I'm very very new to C# and programming in general so any help would go a long way.

Comment: Could update the source code with the full code?

Comment: If you used a DataGridView you could use your list as a datasource.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Sorry John, I'm not sure that I'm understanding what your asking. You want the entirety of the code of the form I'm working on?

Comment: I meant this particular file.

Answer (score 1):

Your selection statement looks correct to me. But since you have to loop through your list to create your final string, I suggest you to refactor everything into a single loop. That will provide you even more control over what's going on with every single element and you should be able to detect the problem:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (ListViewItem i in netchart.SelectedItems)
    sb.Append("\n").Append(i.Text); // Alternatively i.ToString() if appropriate.

output.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: While it is fine to "extend" a `String` *once* using `+`, don't form a habit of doing so in loops: use `StringBuilder.Append("\n").Append(i.Text)`

Comment: You are totally right! I edited my answer following your suggestion!